# Jquery with json response failed

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
enter code here

function test(action,action1,page){

alert("in test");

$.getJSON("./paging.do?action="+escape(action)+"&p="+escape(action1)+"&str="+escape(page), 


function(pageListHolder){

alert("j"+pageListHolder.length);

var options = '';


for (var i = 0; i < pageListHolder.length; i++) {

options += '<option value="' + pageListHolder.key + '">' + pageListHolder.data + '</option>';

}

$("#selectCol").empty();

$("#selectCol").html(options);

}); 



}
```

Above function is called when I click on an element,the above function able to call server.But i didn't see any response data.Could you Please check and let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Raju

Comment: firebug , net panel can fix the issue

Comment: What should your response data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should install firebug and try to see what ajax calls and the response on the net tab.

Your Json might be malformed or the server might have returned an error code like 500 or 404.